# Convert variable name to string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've seen a few other posts about this on Stack Overflow, but the answer always seems to be to create an object with key / value pairs. This doesn't seem to be what I need in my current situation. What I'm wanting to do: I have different arrays which could possibly contain a username. I want to check each array and see if the username is present as a value in them. If it is, I'd like a string representation of a name of the array variable. Example:

```
var array = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape'];
var array2 = ['apple', 'pear', 'plumb']

member_arrays = new Array();
// I'd like this block to be dynamic in that i don't have to specify the array name 
// in the inArray or member_arrays[member_arrays.length+1] (just loop through my arrays
// and add a string representation of the array name to the member_arrays array)
if ($.inArray( 'apple', array ) != -1)
  member_arrays[member_arrays.length] = 'array';
if ($.inArray( 'apple', array2) != -1)
  member_arrays[member_arrays.length] = 'array2';
// etc...
```

Comment: Add parentheses around your `if` block, and the code works as intended, using jQuery (`$.inArray`), eg: `if ($.inArray('apple', array) != -1) member_arrays.push('array');`

Comment: Sorry I've been coding in Coffeescript lately and have been leaving off the parenthesis. The code above WILL work, but I'm wanting to get away from explicitly naming each array in the if statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that in JavaScript.  That's why people suggest using an object and keeping your "variables" as properties in the object.

By the way, when you're appending to an array, you want just the length, not length + 1:

```
member_arrays[member_arrays.length] = 'array';
```

Arrays are zero-based, so the "next" slot is always the "length" value.

*edit* — well, there is a case where you can do that: when your variables are global.  Any global variable named "x" can also be referred to as a property of "window" (for code in a web browser):

```
var x = 3;
alert(window['x']); // alerts "3"
```

Please avoid global variables for this purpose :-)

Comment: Good point about zero-based arrays....pointy. Well, that's discouraging, but I guess I could just make my arrays properties of an object to get around this, eh?

Comment: Yes, you can do that and it works fine. The basic problem is that there's no way to make a "pointer" to a variable, and there's no way to refer to a local scope (that is, there's nothing like "window" for variables local to a function).

Comment: So, to play devil's advocate to your edited option, one COULD do this: `for (i in window) { if ($.inArray ( username, window[i] ) != -1) { member_arrays.push(i); }}`, it's just bad practice?

Comment: Yes you could do that, or make an array of the string names of your variables and iterate over that, looking up the names in "window" as you go. Basically you're just taking advantage of the fact that "window" is already an object, and that's just how global variables work in JavaScript.  (There are lots of properties on "window" of course so just iterating through all of them will cause you to run into a lot of weird things.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do things this way, but putting that aside, here's an approach that approximates what you seem to be looking for. It does use an object, as others have recommended, but you end up with the "answer array" containing the names of the candidate arrays passing the test.

You do use jQuery in your sample, so I've done so as well. But you can also use the plain JavaScript `.indexOf()` the same way.

```
var candidates = {
  'array' : ['apple', 'orange', 'grape'],
  'array2' : ['apple', 'pear', 'plumb']
};
var member_arrays = [];

for( var test in candidates ){
  if( $.inArray( 'apple', candidates[test] ) !== -1 ){ // could use .indexOf()
    member_arrays.push( test ); // use push; no need to specify an index
  }
}

console.log( member_arrays ); // -> ["array","array2"]
```

Comment: Thanks Ken, that's the approach I ended up taking. You mention you're not sure why I'd want to do it this way...can you offer an alternative way to find this info out that's better?