# JavaScript convert variable name into string

Tags: javascript, string, variables, undefined, alert

I have a function like:

```
function testFunction( option )
{
  alert(option);
}
```

(the actual function does more than just answer the option)

And of course, it works if you do `testFunction("qwerty");`, or `testFunction(myvar);`, where `myvar` is a variable.

It does not work if I do `testFunction(qwerty);`, where qwerty is not a variable, as expected.

I was wondering if there is a way to make the function check to see if `option` is a variable or string (such as `"qwerty"` and `myvar` in the examples above) and if it is continue as normal and alert the string or the variable's value.

However, if it is not a variable or string, but is an undefined variable (such as `qwerty` in the example above) then I would like it to alert the name of the variable (`qwerty` in this case).

Is this possible?

Thanks!

**Some more examples:**

```
var myvar = "1234";
testFunction("test"); //alerts "test"
testFunction(myvar);  //alerts "1234"
testFunction(qwerty); //alert "qwerty"
```

Comment: There is a question with (close to) exact same title available on SO. See SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983896/convert-variable-name-to-string-in-javascript

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: What's the purpose of this anyway?

Comment: That's an XY problem. Why do you want to do this? I've never come across a case where this was needed.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/293/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that testFunction(qwerty); will not even reach the function.

Javascript cannot interpret the variable 'qwerty' as it is not defined, so it will crash right there.

Just for fun, here's a way to do what you request, by catching the error thrown when you try to interpret an undefined variable :

```
function testFunction( option ){
      console.log(option);   
}


try {
    var myvar = "1234";
    testFunction("test"); //alerts "test"
    testFunction(myvar); 
    testFunction(qwerty); //alert "qwerty" 
}catch(e){
    if(e.message.indexOf('is not defined')!==-1){
       var nd = e.message.split(' ')[0];
       testFunction(nd);
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wx01jauy/3/)

Bear in mind that you should absolutely never do that, instead, try using existing variables in your programs, it works better ;)